# One shot pulse Push Button

Tags: capacitor, resistors, pulse

How could I make a circuit where whenever a push button is pressed, the output would be a single pulse ? The pulses duration has to always be the same regardless of how long the button is held down. What would be the simplest way of doing this (ideally only using discrete components, so no 555 timers) ?

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: Why do you want to do this with only discretes? The 555 - or a microcontroller - are ideally suited to this task.

Comment: I agree with Nick-- that's what the 555 is designed to do. Why wouldn't you want to use it?

Comment: You're absolutely right, the 555 would be the right way to go. I just need to find the most cost efficient way possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the simplest way without the 555 timer. You have to play with the RC values and the gate's input should be schmitt triggered.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOmoDc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That just plain won't work. You need, at the very least, pullups on both sides of the cap.

Comment: Good point. I fixed that.